# Speed of light in higher-dimensional space

Tags: science-based, physics, faster-than-light, spacetime-dimensions

In science fiction, one of the widely used tricks for achieving faster-than-light motion is traveling through "hyperspace". By that I mean, entering a space with more than 3 spatial dimensions, like 4D, 5D, or any other amount of dimensions.

However, this makes me wonder. From a scientific point of view, would the speed of light in such higher-dimensional spaces be different? Like faster, or maybe slower? Or would there be no difference?

Let's say for the sake of simplicity that aside from the number of dimensions, all other parameters in that other "hyperspace" are similar to ours.

Comment: Please indicate where have you found a variant of the Maxwell equations which works in a four-dimensional space... The point being that in the same place you will find a derivation of the speed of electromagnetic waves in such a space. In other words, what did your diligent research reveal about how electromagnetism might (or might not) work in a space with more than three dimensions?

Comment: I don't know much about physics but i am pretty sure that light in higher dimensions has the same speed as in 3D. Also the reasons why the the **Sub  Space ** allow FTL is that that that they are smaller than their **Hub Space**. This allows a shorter traveling distance for example 1 Meters in an Subspace maybe 10 Meters in the Hub dimensions. This there fore allows you just to crossback over to the Hub world when you practically reached your destination in the Subspace. There is really in a practical sense no FTL involved.

Comment: VTC:Not About Worldbuilding per the Help Center. I can't find a worldbuilding problem in your question. This appears to be a question better suited to [physics.se] in that you're asking if any mathematical model of a hyperspatial condition supports a change in the speed of light. In short, per the [help/on-topic], we're here to help you build an imaginary world of your own creation. What help do you need with that?

Comment: In physics. both the dimensons of our spacetime, and also the speed of light, are free parameters. With other words, to our best knowledge, they have nothing to do to each other.

Comment: I think that this question is one that Greg Egan faced when creating the universe for Diaspora. It might not be something that's specific to a planet, but is essential to understand when coming up with an FTL theory.

Comment: @RobertRapplean I'd be happy with that... if the OP actually said it. As it is, this feels like idle curiosity, which the help center calls [mindless social fun](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). P.S., I loved Egan's *Orthogonal* books.

Comment: (@cconsta1 Note that both 'traveling' (BE) and 'travelling' (AE) are correct spellings :)

Answer (score 6):

If there are more dimensions, it won't change the speed of light. How hyperspace works is that you shift to a space where the distance between two points is shorter.

Consider a person running across the surface of the Earth at a thousand miles per hour. Yea, he's the Flash. His angular velocity is roughly 1/24th of the circumference of the globe per hour.

Now let's move him to a globe that is 1/24th as big. Let's say this is a Hollow Earth thing, and there's a tiny Earth inside of ours. At 1000 mph, he's running around the entire globe once per hour. He can run from the US to Australia in half an hour.

That's how hyperspace works. It's not that you're taking advantage of more dimensions. It's that when you move along one of the hidden dimensions, all of the other dimensions get smaller. If the other dimensions don't get smaller, you gain nothing by traversing them and you lose the time required for traversal.

You will want to consider the propagation issue, though. Radiation and gravity in our universe both drop in intensity based on the square of the distance. If this is really a four-dimensional world, then such things would drop off at the cube of the distance. This breaks a lot of things. For instance, [there are no stable orbits in 4-space,](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/50142/gravity-in-other-than-3-spatial-dimensions-and-stable-orbits) so no planets.

Comment: Is the fact that gravity and radiation etc. drop off on the square of distance proof then that there are no higher dimensions of space?

Comment: @Taylrl, It's evidence of it, but not proof. It's also possible that those dimensions exist, but that light and gravity don't propagate through them.